# URL Rewrite (WAMP): Drop "index.php" from the URL (for a Codeigniter project with customized folder structure)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

First off,  knowing that this question has probably been asked 1.5 million times, I did Google it.
I've read and tried a *bunch* of suggestions, but the problem still persists.

This is our first inhouse CI project.
A skeleton "project" was created with a non-standard (in the CI world) directory tree to better match the file structure of our other existing projects.
It goes something like this:

> ../
>   /www
>   - index.php
>   /application
>   - /config
>   - /controllers
>   - /...etc
>   - /lib
>   - - /vendor
>   - - - /codeIgniter
>   - - - - /2-1-2
>   - - - - - /system
>   - - - - - - /...etc
>   - /library
>   - /views
>   - /...etc

I copied it to my machine (WAMP) and tested a couple controllers.
Everything seems to work fine. The only hitch is that *index.php* is still required in the url.
I'd like to be able to use *http://localhost/project/controller/method*, rather than needing *http://localhost/project/**index.php**/controller/method*.

I confirmed that my http.conf has `AllowOverrride All` for *wamp/www*, and I added an `.htaccess` file to the */www* directory ... to no avail :(

```
### \www\.htaccess ### 
# After many tries, I reverted to these simple 4 lines and stopped here

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have this Alias for the project

```
### \wamp\alias\bomProject.conf ###

Alias /bomProject/ "c:/wamp/NetBeansProjects/bomProject/www/" 

<Directory "c:/wamp/NetBeansProjects/bomProject/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This alias allows me to successfully browse the project at *http://localhost/bomproject*.
I have set `$config['index_page']` in my */config/config.php* to `''`

I've also tried changing `$config['base_url']   = ''`
to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/bomProject/'` in *config.php* ... neither worked.

**My suspicion** is that the issue boils down to our dir tree, but **I'm too inexperienced with htaccess**, and regex for that matter, to know how to solve it.

**[EDIT]:**
 
@chris-clower introduced me to *config/routes.php*, so I read up on it a little.
Very good to know! I'm much appreciative and I enjoyed playing with 'em ... it's just that, according to the documentation (*how I understand it at least*), I don't think routes are the solution to my problem.
When trying "*localhost/bomProject/{controller}*" ... where *{controller}* would obviously be a real controller name ... I still get this 404 error: "*Not Found - The requested URL /wamp/NetBeansProjects/BomProject/www/index.php/{controller} was not found on this server.*" 
**[/EDIT]:**

Any help will be ***greatly*** appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look in `/application/config/routes.php` and add your routes there, similar to this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/index/';
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1';
$route['forum'] = 'forum/index/';
$route['(:any)'] = 'index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

As for your `.htaccess`, it looks fine and shouldn't require any changes for this.

Comment: @mOrloff it should be noted that the above requires, in this example, a controller for `admin` and another for `forum` in `application/controllers/`.

Comment: alright, we've got a sample controller called "sandbox" with two methods, "index" and "tester" ... with my routes as `$route['default_controller'] = 'index';
$route['sandbox'] = 'sandbox/tester/';
$route['404_override'] = '';` I am able to control where I land when calling the "/sandbox" controller ... but it is still requiring ***index.php** in the url ... otherwise I get a 404 ... thoughts ????

Comment: @mOrloff `$route['sandbox'] = 'sandbox/index/'; $route['sandbox/(:any)'] = 'sandbox/$1';`

Comment: Thanks for those. While requests do get routed correclty, INDEX.PHP is still needed in the url. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Try adding a `/` at the beginning of index.php in the .htaccess file where you have: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`, like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`. Also, before that line, try adding this as well: `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)`. I'm grasping here, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks! Prepending with that slash `/` did ***something*** at least ... if I call for **ANY** controller, it now loads WAMP Welcome page (_typically only found at http://localhost_) ... not what we're going for, but it's exciting to see _SOMETHING_ happen nonetheless :)

Comment: @mOrloff ah, that'll happen if you add the `/` while using `http://localhost/mysite/` (as `/` is server root based on domain), so take the `/` out. Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in WAMP? Click the WAMP icon int he system try, and then go to Apache -> Apache Modules and make sure **Rewrite Module** has a check next to it (if not, you can click on it there to enable it). **Restart WAMP after enabling or it will appear not to have worked** :)

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that .. I confirm that mod-rewrite is enabled. ....... any other ideas ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15196/discussion-between-morloff-and-chris-clower)